# SQL values not being added

Tags: php, mysql, instagram

I'm trying to use this API to test and play around with on my website.
None of the SQL Values are being stored into the tables however I'm still being logged in and able to see the data I received from the IG Api

This is the success page that receives the info from ig to be put into tables

```
<?php
require 'db.php';
require 'instagram.class.php';
require 'instagram.config.php';

// Receive OAuth code parameter
$code = $_GET['code'];



// Check whether the user has granted access
if (true === isset($code)) {

// Receive OAuth token object
$data = $instagram->getOAuthToken($code);
  // Take a look at the API response

if(empty($data->user->username))
{
header('Location: index.php');

}
else
{
session_start();
$_SESSION['userdetails']=$data;
$user=$data->user->username;
$fullname=$data->user->full_name;
$bio=$data->user->bio;
$website=$data->user->website;
$id=$data->user->id;
$token=$data->access_token;

$id=mysql_query("select instagram_id from instagram_users where instagram_id='$id'");

if(mysql_num_rows($id) = 0)
{   
mysql_query("insert into instagram_users(username,Name,Bio,Website,instagram_id,instagram_access_token) values('$user','$fullname','$bio','$website','$id','$token')");
}

header('Location: home.php');
}
} 
else 
{
// Check whether an error occurred
if (true === isset($_GET['error'])) 
{
echo 'An error occurred: '.$_GET['error_description'];
}

}

?>
```

but... if I changed the data to lets say

```
mysql_query("insert into instagram_users(username,Name,Bio,Website,instagram_id,instagram_access_token) values('foo','bar','foo','bar.com','0','foo')");
```

then it would work just fine.

Echoing into my mysql_num_rows gives me pretty much all the same info as var dump BESIDES resource numer 6? whatever that is it seems wrong

```
    insert into instagram_users(username,Name,Bio,Website,instagram_id,instagram_access_token) values('myigusername','my name was here','hey this is where a bio would go','tumblr.com/foobar','Resource id #6','49749frgrgr5tt55558a64r435454t5tfrgefdg') –
```

Comment: what do get for `var_dump($data)` ?

Comment: stop using mysql_* has been deprecated use mysqli or PDO

Comment: I wager that if you echo your statement just prior to executing it, you will find one of your variables is empty and causing the insert to fail.

Comment: `mysql_query( 'your query') or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: A typo? `if(mysql_num_rows($id) = 0)` . You are assigning a value to `mysql_num_rows` instead of comparing. Try `if(mysql_num_rows($id)==0)`

Comment: It's a typing mistake, use "==" in if(mysql_num_rows($id) = 0)

Comment: I was randomly trying to edit things to figure out why this wasn't working so that's why it's = and not == but even at == 0 i get no errors everything runs fine it's just not storing any data

Comment: var_dump gets me
object(stdClass)#2 (2) { ["access_token"]=> string(49) "49749232232238a6c775.3e8cf3133443045e49ba17263d0bededa" ["user"]=> object(stdClass)#3 (6) { ["username"]=> string(11) "myigusername" ["bio"]=> string(139) "hey this is where a bio would go . " ["website"]=> string(43) "http://tumblrurlwouldgohee.tumblr.com" ["profile_picture"]=> string(76) "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_pictureurlwouldgohere.jpg" ["full_name"]=> string(15) "My name was here" ["id"]=> string(8) "8383827" } } 

replaced some info but it did give me all my information

Comment: For the sake of debugging, inside `if(mysql_num_rows == 0)`, put the following and see what is echoed out `echo "insert into instagram_users(username,Name,Bio,Website,instagram_id,instagram_access_token) values('$user','$fullname','$bio','$website','$id','$token')"; die();`

Comment: Echoing that into my mysql_num_rows gives me pretty much all the same info as var dump BESIDES resource numer 6? whatever that is it seems wrong

insert into instagram_users(username,Name,Bio,Website,instagram_id,instagram_access_token) values('myigusername','my name was here','hey this is where a bio would go','tumblr.com/foobar','Resource id #6','49749frgrgr5tt55558a64r435454t5tfrgefdg')

Comment: Of course! `$id` is a mysql resource. You need to use `mysql_fetch_array` to get the `instagram_id` from that resource. However, that should not come in the way of a successful insert though.

Comment: the id row in my instagram_users table is an INT value.
could that be why it isn't inserting?
any idea how I would go about using a fetch arrary in my
        ('$user','$fullname','$bio','$website','$id','$token')
code?

Answer (score 2):

```
if(mysql_num_rows($id) = 0)
```

should be

```
if(mysql_num_rows($id) == 0)
```

Comment: sorry that was an edit I made it's already == 0 atm still no change